# Add a track to an iTunes Playlist from an ID with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm trying to add a song to a playlist from an iTunes ID (ie: 656479918), I also have some data from the iTunes search API if it helps. 
How can I add this track to an existing playlist in iTunes with AppleScript?

```
{ 
  wrapperType: 'track',
  kind: 'song',
  artistId: 1249595,
  collectionId: 656479857,
  trackId: 656479918,
  artistName: 'The Rolling Stones',
  collectionName: 'Let It Bleed',
  trackName: 'Monkey Man',
  collectionCensoredName: 'Let It Bleed',
  trackCensoredName: 'Monkey Man',
  artistViewUrl: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/the-rolling-stones/id1249595?uo=4',
  collectionViewUrl: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/monkey-man/id656479857?i=656479918&uo=4',
  trackViewUrl: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/monkey-man/id656479857?i=656479918&uo=4',
  previewUrl: 'http://a749.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music6/v4/0d/f1/99/0df1995a-02d6-d67c-7d67-1817008e43d7/mzaf_5915143712191719844.plus.aac.p.m4a',
  artworkUrl30: 'http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music2/v4/76/e2/45/76e245d4-37dc-3597-8f89-75d6bc384923/source/30x30bb.jpg',
  artworkUrl60: 'http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music2/v4/76/e2/45/76e245d4-37dc-3597-8f89-75d6bc384923/source/60x60bb.jpg',
  artworkUrl100: 'http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music2/v4/76/e2/45/76e245d4-37dc-3597-8f89-75d6bc384923/source/100x100bb.jpg',
  collectionPrice: 9.99,
  trackPrice: 1.29,
  releaseDate: '2013-01-01T08:00:00Z',
  collectionExplicitness: 'notExplicit',
  trackExplicitness: 'notExplicit',
  discCount: 1,
  discNumber: 1,
  trackCount: 9,
  trackNumber: 8,
  trackTimeMillis: 251825,
  country: 'USA',
  currency: 'USD',
  primaryGenreName: 'Rock',
  isStreamable: true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your track is in variable TR (class = track), then you can add and remove from playlist "myList" as follow :

```
-- move track to playlist:
Tell application "iTunes" to duplicate TR to playlist "myList"

-- remove track from playlist:
Tell application "iTunes" to delete TR of user playlist "myList"
```

Keep in mind that iTunes is asynchronous : for instance the delete command may not be executed immediately, but after some time.

Comment: Thanks, but how to initialize the track from an iTunes ID or an URL?

Comment: the way you define track depends where the track is : which playlist, which source. For instance : "set myTrack to every file track of user playlist id xxxx of source id yy whose ID is zzzz" will create a list of 1 item with ID zzzz, if the playlist  whose id is xxxx from the source.